# Mysql count record on condition, multiple fields selected

Tags: mysql, count, case

Im trying use count case to count records in a certain column (runs.Finish) if they equal one.

I cant seem to get this to work when I add count case like I have on the third line below.

```
SELECT
  `jockeys`.`JockeyInitials`,
  `jockeys`.`JockeySurName` ,
  COUNT(  `runs`.`JockeysID` ), 
  COUNT( CASE WHEN `runs`.`Finish`=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS `runs`.`Finish` , 
  SUM(  `runs`.`StakeWon` ) 
FROM runs, jockeys
WHERE  `runs`.`JockeysID` =  `jockeys`.`JockeysID` 
  AND  `runs`.`JockeysID` >=1
  AND  `runs`.`JockeysID` <=100
GROUP BY  `runs`.`JockeysID`
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you do not use the `FROM runs, jockeys` implicit join notation and instead always use the explicit JOIN notation, such as `FROM runs JOIN jockeys ON runs.JockeysID = jockeys.JockeysID`.  You need to know the other notation in order to read old-style SQL, but make a point of not using it yourself.

Comment: You should also describe what happens more than "I can't seem to get this to work"; in what way doesn't it work?  Syntax error?  Wrong result?

Comment: It was a syntax error, apologies for being vague. Thanks for your recommendation wrt explicit JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be (check group by columns and alias for your case statement column)

```
SELECT
  `jockeys`.`JockeyInitials`,
  `jockeys`.`JockeySurName` ,
  COUNT(  `runs`.`JockeysID` ), 
  COUNT( CASE WHEN `runs`.`Finish`=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS `Finish` , 
  SUM(  `runs`.`StakeWon` ) 
FROM runs, jockeys
WHERE  `runs`.`JockeysID` =  `jockeys`.`JockeysID` 
  AND  `runs`.`JockeysID` >=1
  AND  `runs`.`JockeysID` <=100
GROUP BY  `jockeys`.`JockeyInitials`,
  `jockeys`.`JockeySurName`
```

Comment: That worked. As per Jonathan Leffler suggestion I will try to use an explicit JOIN. I know Im not supposed to say thank you but I can't help it, thanks guys this was helpful!